# Laravel 6 ErrorException Undefined variable: user (...home.blade.php)

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-6, laravel-6.2

I am trying to show every user's name from the database in the home.blade.php. I am getting this error:

```
ErrorException
Undefined variable: user (View...home.blade.php)

$user is undefined
Make the variable optional in the blade template. Replace {{ $user }} with {{ $user ?? '' }}
```

Below is the code in home.blade.php:

```
<!-- SQL statement select all profiles except logged user -->

foreach ($user as $users)
   <h6>{{ $user->name }}</h6>
endforeach
```

Below is the code in HomeController.php

```
public function index()
    {
        $users = Users::where('id', '!=', auth()->id())->get();

        return view('home');
    }
```

Comment: "_Below is the code in home.blade.php_" That's not `blade` syntax

Comment: The Laravel documentation has [Passing Data To Views](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/views#passing-data-to-views) that shows ... how to pass data to a view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your HomeController.php

`return view('home', ['users' => $users]);`

And your foreach should be:

```
@foreach($users as $user)
     <h6>{{ $user->name }}</h6>
@endforeach
```